# To avoid repeating "one"

Tags: writing-style, technical

In my technical writings, I have a lot of instruction lists that describe how to use "something" under different circumstances. To avoid repetition of the subject, I replace it with "one", but it doesn't resolve the fact of the repetition itself.

A very childish example:

> - If you want to look offensive, wear a red shirt.
> - If you want to look fresh, wear a white **one**.
> - When you are in doubt, wear a green **one**.
> - If you are worried that the shirt might become dirty very quickly, wear a black **one**.

"one", "one", "one". Three times. What is the way to fix such a repeating without breaking the consistency? By breaking the consistency I mean something illogical, like this:

> - If you want to look offensive, wear a red **shirt**.
> - If you want to look fresh, wear a white **shirt**.
> - When you are in doubt, wear a green **one**.
> - If you are worried that a shirt might become dirty very quickly, wear a black **one**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109356/discussion-on-question-by-john-c-j-to-avoid-repeating-one).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of

> - If you want to look offensive, wear a red shirt.
> - If you want to look fresh, wear a white **one**.
> - When you are in doubt, wear a green **one**.
> - If you are worried that the shirt might become dirty very quickly, wear a black **one**.

You could introduce some variations like:

> - If you want to look offensive, wear a red shirt.
> - If you want to look fresh, wear a white **one**.
> - When you are in doubt, go with green.
> - If you are worried that the shirt might become dirty very quickly, try black instead.

This breaks the monotony of the repetitions without changing the meaning.

Comment: As a somewhat terser monotony breaker, one could replace the third and fourth with "When you are in doubt, where green. If you are worried that ...., wear black."

Comment: While this provides the kind of answer OP asked for, I think a **correct** answer would be, "You are asking the wrong question." Repetition is not a defect in technical writing. If the repetition really is extreme, it may indicate that the information should be presented in a table (as suggested in a comment under the question).

Comment: Technical writing does not work like that. It's an instruction manual, not a leisure journal.

Comment: @PrimeMover the principle still applies though.  Perhaps a technical writer would be more likely to say "select green" or "use black" rather than "go with green" or "try black."

Comment: @phoog A professional technical writer would not use such a flabby and wordy construction in the first place, but would present the options in a table.

Comment: @DavidK There is quite a wide range of writings that are considered technical writing. Since the OP asked for a certain kind of answer, it would be fine to answer the question, although anybody is free to add in their answer that they think the OP is asking the wrong question. Since we don't necessarily know all the relevant details of the writing that the OP is asking about (who is the audience? in this domain of knowledge, do they tend to follow certain guidelines? and so on), I would prefer to give the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: What is generally acceptable in normal technical writing? Certain goals, like the need for clarity and lack of ambiguity, are generally agreed upon by most people. However, there are differences in opinion on how to achieve those goals. Some professional writers discuss creativity and technical writing in https://devrix.com/tutorial/expert-tips-foster-creativity-in-technical-writing/#:~:text=Being%20creative%20in%20technical%20writing,and%20it's%20easy%20to%20consume. Dryness is not a goal of technical writing.

Comment: Here's a quotation from that web page: "Technical doesn’t have to mean dry. Infusing technical writing with conversational, recognizable language not only makes the piece more interesting to read but also makes it easier for readers to digest." In my answer, I wasn't aiming for "elegant variation", but much more modest variations that were keeping with the tone of voice and slightly conversational style as asked by the OP.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, that would be another way.  Jason Bassford has provided an answer along those lines too.

Answer (score 43):

My personal view is that the repeated use of "one" is not a problem at all. Tying yourself up in more and more convoluted linguistic circumlocutions so as to avoid what is at base a numinous rule: "Don't repeat yourself", is to be guarded against if you are aiming first and foremost for clarity and ease of understanding. And in the art of technical writing, clarity is foremost.

For further emphasis about the clarity of exposition, my own personal style in mathematical writing is not to use pronouns *at all*, because it is too easy to fall into the trap of being ambiguous, which in mathematics won't do at all.

If you do find yourself needing to repeat the same sentence pattern as in the above, you may want to think about formally structuring, for example:

"Guide to shirt colour:

- Red: to look offensive;
- White: to look fresh;
- Green: if you are in doubt;
- Black: if you are worried that it may become dirty too quickly."

Comment: +1 to "not a problem at all". Fowler, in his classic book "Modern English Usage", calls the attempts to remedy this non-problem "pointless variation" which often introduces more ambiguity. Sadly I can't find an electronic version of his rant here, but it's quite amusing.

Comment: So much of Fowler is no more than basic common sense applied to the problem of making oneself understood.

Comment: I think Fowler called it “elegant variation” and parodied an opera synopsis. I can’t find it at the moment, but it is on the lines of switching between Ronaldo, the count, our hero and the rejected suitor. Another reason I upvoted your answer is that the question refers to technical writing, in which such variation is poison as it raises a doubt in the reader’s mind whether the author is referring to the same thing. I have beaten it out of generations of students (as we did in the good old days).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation#:~:text=Elegant%20variation%20is%20the%20use,avoid%20repeating%20the%20same%20word.&text=Henry%20Watson%20Fowler%20(1858%E2%80%931933,elegant%20variation%20for%20this%20phenomenon.

Comment: +1, but the readers of this answer should keep in mind that "not a problem at all" here is only in the context of technical writing. This is indeed the context of the current thread, but it's easy to miss this fact (I had initially).

Comment: @Ruslan No, it's not a problem at all in *any* context. Flowery prolixity has no place except maybe in some of the more rubbish poems written by dippy schoolgirls.

Answer (score 15):

Since this is technical writing, the concise nature of tables is appropriate and may make the information easier to scan quickly. You could try something like:

```
Vary your shirt color to achieve different goals according to the table below:

    Goal             |  Shirt color
    ==============================
    Appear offensive | Red
    Look fresh       | White
    Express doubt    | Green
    Hide dirt        | Black
```

The table format helps to enforce parallel structure.  It reduces redundancy in the use of "one," but also avoids repetition of the introductory, "If you want to..." and of the verb "wear..."

Answer (score 7):

Simply drop the indefinite article and the noun.

Instead of saying *wear* ***a*** *red* ***shirt***, simply say *wear red*.

If you need to mention shirts at some point, you can provide an introductory sentence to this list.

> When it comes to shirts, consider the following:
>
> - If you want to look offensive, wear red.
> - If you want to look fresh, wear white.
> - When you are in doubt, wear green.
> - If you are worried that a shirt might become dirty very quickly, wear black.

Comment: So, red shirt, white pants, green socks, black shoes!

Comment: Guy Keleny teaches that "When it comes to" is flabby journalese which is best avoided.

Comment: @PrimeMover one could nonetheless rewrite to avoid "when it comes to" without diminishing the usefulness of this answer.

Comment: @KannE That's the man. He's wise.

Comment: @phoog which is why I added it as a comment rather than expressing my disagreement with a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would gradually simplify by dropping verbs and nouns when readers can easily infer them from the context:

> If you want to look offensive, wear a red shirt. To look fresh, a white one. When in doubt, green. Worried that the shirt might become dirty very quickly, black.